# How to check if dynamic is empty.

Tags: c#, .net, json, dynamic, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft's Json.NET to deserialize a JSON string:

```
var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("{ 'foo': 'bar' }");
```

How can I check that `output` is empty? An example test case:

```
var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("{ }");
Assert.IsNull(output); // fails
```

Comment: Should the output from "{ }" be empty/null? I would expect it to create a generic object with no properties. I would expect that deserialising "[ ]" would create an array object with no elements.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The object you get back from DeserializeObject is going to be a JObject, which has a `Count` property. This property tells you how many properties are on the object.

```
var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("{ }");

if (((JObject)output).Count == 0)
{
    // The object is empty
}
```

This won't tell you if a dynamic object is empty, but it will tell you if a deserialized JSON object is empty.

Comment: [According to the docs](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm), `DeserializeObject` returns `T`, which will not be a `JObject`.

Comment: dynamic is not an actual type so Json.NET falls back to using JObject.

Comment: I had to do something similar today and this helped, but I needed to adjust it to: `((JToken)output).Count()`

Answer (score 3):

You can also check with following code:

```
var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("{ }");
if (output as JObject == null)
{
}
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can just have a string conversion and check if its equal to "{ }".

```
var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("{ }");

if (output.ToString() =="{ }")
{
    // The object is empty
}
```